# How add a custom field to the generated Swagger json from SpringFox?

Tags: swagger, springfox

I'm trying to add the field `externalDocs` to the [generated Json](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore-with-external-docs.json) from Springfox:

```
"externalDocs": {
    "description": "find more info here",
    "url": "https://swagger.io/about"
},
```

Reading the SpringFox documentation, I understand that I need to create a `plugin` to extends the SpringFox funcionalities and add this field. I tried:

```
@Component
@Order(SwaggerPluginSupport.SWAGGER_PLUGIN_ORDER + 1002)
@Slf4j
public class ExternalDocSwaggerConfiguration implements ApiListingBuilderPlugin {

    @Override
    public void apply(final ApiListingContext apiListingContext) {

        ObjectVendorExtension ext = new ObjectVendorExtension("externalDocs");
        ext.addProperty(new StringVendorExtension("description", "Link externo"));
        ext.addProperty(new StringVendorExtension("url", "https://swagger.io/about"));
        apiListingContext.apiListingBuilder().extensions(
            Collections.singletonList(ext)); // extensions does not exist
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(final DocumentationType documentationType) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I was expecting to add the extension, as showed [here](https://github.com/indrabasak/swagger-deepdive/wiki/Custom-Operation-Builder-Plugin#custom-plugin) with the `OperationBuilderPlugin`, but there is no `extensions` method on the `apiListingBuilder`.

So, how could I add this tag on the root of the generated Swagger Json using SpringFox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version 2.7.0 added [this feature](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/pull/1761).

To add this field `externalDocs`, you can use the `extensions` method from the `Docket`:

```
@Bean
public Docket customImplementation() {

    ObjectVendorExtension ext = new ObjectVendorExtension("externalDocs");
    ext.addProperty(new StringVendorExtension("description", "Link externo"));
    ext.addProperty(new StringVendorExtension("url", "https://swagger.io/about"));

    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .extensions(Collections.singletonList(ext))
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .securitySchemes(newArrayList(apiKey()))
            .pathMapping("/api")
            .securityContexts(newArrayList(securityContext())).select()
            .apis(getPackages())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
```